# Cannot assign to property: 'absoluteString' is a get-only property

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to fill the textfield with the current web page url but i'm getting this error

> Cannot assign to property: 'absoluteString' is a get-only property

```
         @ObservedObject var navigationState = NavigationState()

         //Address bar
         TextField("username", text: Binding<String>(
            get: {self.navigationState.url?.absoluteString ?? ""},
            set: {self.navigationState.url?.absoluteString = $0 }))
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .padding(.top, 1.5)
            .onSubmit {
                ............
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be created URL from string, like

```
 TextField("username", text: Binding<String>(
    get: {self.navigationState.url?.absoluteString ?? ""},
    set: {self.navigationState.url = URL(string: $0) }))
```